# VM and host time drift during suspend

Tags: systemd, ntp, real-time

I am running Ubuntu 16.04 on my laptop, with Ubuntu 14.04 in a Vagrant VM in VirtualBox. My laptop is running SystemD and network time is enabled:

```
naftuli@reprisal:~$ sudo timedatectl status
      Local time: Sun 2016-12-25 15:21:33 PST
  Universal time: Sun 2016-12-25 23:21:33 UTC
        RTC time: Sun 2016-12-25 23:21:33
       Time zone: America/Los_Angeles (PST, -0800)
 Network time on: yes
NTP synchronized: yes
 RTC in local TZ: no
```

The VM, lacking SystemD, is running the NTP daemon:

```
vagrant@ubuntu-14:/vagrant$ wololo ntpdc -c sysinfo
system peer:          0.0.0.0
system peer mode:     unspec
leap indicator:       11
stratum:              16
precision:            -19
root distance:        0.00000 s
root dispersion:      0.00717 s
reference ID:         [73.78.73.84]
reference time:       00000000.00000000  Mon, Jan  1 1900  0:00:00.000
system flags:         auth monitor ntp kernel stats
jitter:               0.000000 s
stability:            0.000 ppm
broadcastdelay:       0.000000 s
authdelay:            0.000000 s
```

However, if and when I suspend my laptop, the VM time drifts significantly it seems, and despite both my laptop and VM purportedly syncing to NTP timeservers, I have a huge drift:

[image]

For comparison, in this screenshot the host time is `23:23:56`, VM time is `23:22:47`.

Importantly, this clock drift means that AWS API calls fail due to their cryptographic dependence on accurate clocks.

How can I minimize or eliminate clock drift between the VM and real time?

Comment: Either get the time synchronized more frequently or stop suspending the host.

Comment: @JuliePelletier Is there a manual command I can run on a cron job or something to get the time on the VM synchronized more often?

Comment: If it's in the crontab, then you can just change when it runs from that crontab entry.  `man 5 crontab` will show you what fields represent so you can adjust it.  For `ntpd` which seems to be what your VM is using, check `man ntpd` and look for `--updateinterval`.